# Concurrent Cache modification in Java

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, thread-safety

I am building a small cache with a Map which holds a cached result for some DB query. Assume that this cache is filled in a thread safe way. My question is about the entries in this cache, the objects of type Result.

Consider the following scenario:

Thread 1 reads from the cache and gets some Result object, call it R.
Thread 2 wants the same object R to be killed so it makes a call to the cache kill the object R.

Seeing how both threads hold only a reference to the object R, there is a possibility that the object R suddenly becomes null for thread 1 since thread 2 has made a call to kill it.

How do I avoid this? Should I make a deep copy of the object R when a thread reads from the cache so that even if thread 2 kills the cache, then thread 1 will still be able to finish what it was doing without issues? Or is there another approach to this? My experience with threads and concurrency is not the biggest so be gentle...

Comment: You need to show the entire Result type, since it matters for this question; generally speaking, an immutable or properly-synchronized Result will be fine. Remember that an *object* can't be null, only a *reference* to an object. If thread 1 grabbed a valid reference before thread 2 evicted R from the cache, the reference itself remains valid.

Comment: It depends on your **killing** mechanism! If you just remove it from them Map, then nothing happens to thread 1's logic, because it holds its reference, but if you modify it (for example by nullifying its members), then thread 1 will encounter problems.

Comment: You only cache the **references** to Objects, so there will be no problem as long as you do not alter the object itself when removing (as @AmirPashazadeh mentioned). Another thing: if possible i suggest you to use a cache library such as [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/) or a [Guava Cache](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained).

Comment: @ortang you are of course right about that I only cache the references. Should have thought of that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- generally you treat Result as a *value object*. Thread 2 would remove it from the cache/ or overwrite the cache with a newer value, but would not generally damage/destroy the *internal state* of R.

Thread 2 "putting null into the cache" or "putting a new value into the cache" would not, of itself, affect any other references or threads using R. Nothing inside R will break, unless you specifically break it.. code requesting an object from the cache just won't be given that particular reference to R, anymore.

The pointer/or reference will change or be set to null, the state & fields of R itself won't.

This assumes that R doesn't hold resources that need to be freed..

If R *did* need to hold resources, which is not the usual case, then you might need to add an *in-use counter* and count both being in-use by being held in cache & being in-use by client code,  such that R's resources only got released when the counter decremented to zero.

But this would be an unusual requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If your "kill" operation modifies the internals of Result then you could have this problem.
If it doesn't then no, the reference for the thread that already received it from the cache cannot become null. Deleting object from the map does not make references null.